# Angular 6 - How can I refactor the code for these controls

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

I have an app that makes pretty extensive use of Angular Material autocomplete controls.  We are using them to allow users to select email addresses that can be attached to a form.  Here's how we're using them

```
<mat-form-field class="input-width-500">
   <mat-chip-list #recipientChipList>
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let email of emailRecipients" 
         (removed)="removeEmailList(email)">{email}}
            <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
          </mat-chip>
          <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Add Recipients" 
            formControlName="addRecipient"
            [matAutocomplete]="autoRecipient" 
            [matChipInputFor]="recipientChipList" 
            (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addEmail($event)">
        </mat-chip-list>
        <mat-autocomplete #autoRecipient="matAutocomplete" 
          [displayWith]="displayEmailIds"
          (optionSelected)="addEmailList($event)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let val of filteredRecipients" [value]="val">
            {{val}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
```

and the back end code to add the emails:

```
addEmail(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
  const input = event.input;
  const value = event.value;
  if (!this.autoRecipient.isOpen) {
    if (input && value !== '') {
        this.emailRecipients.push(value);
      input.value = '';
    }
   }
    input.value = '';
   }
```

And it's working fine, but we have four of these on a page for different types of emails (CC, BCC, etc) and they all work the same way the only difference being the references to the autocomplete control and the array that the emails get pushed to once selected.  I'm trying to find a way to refactor the addEmail function so that we only have the one function but so far I seem to be overcomplicating it.  Looking for some general direction here, thanks in advance.

EDIT:

So I've added this to the template:

```
(matChipInputTokenEnd)="newAddEmail($event, autoRecipient, addRecipientCtrl, emailRecipients)"
```

and this to the back end:

```
newAddEmail(event: MatChipInputEvent, autoControl: MatAutocomplete, recipientControl: AbstractControl, emailArray: any[]): void {

const input = event.input;
const value = event.value;
if (!autoControl.isOpen) {
  if (input && value !== '') {
      emailArray.push(value);
      input.value = '';
  }
}
input.value = '';
```

}

Comment: Why don't you simply pass the control and the array as argument to addEmail(), in addition to the event?

Comment: That's the direction I was going, can you help me with how to reference those once they're passed in?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You reference them by just using the new parameter name. As in any other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass the two properties as additional arguments to your method:

```
(optionSelected)="addEmailList($event, autoRecipient, emailRecipients)">
```

[...]

```
addEmail(event: MatChipInputEvent, autoComplete: MatAutoComplete, recipients: Array<Something>) {
  const input = event.input;
  const value = event.value;
  if (!autoComplete.isOpen) {
    if (input && value !== '') {
      recipients.push(value);
      input.value = '';
    }
  }
  input.value = '';
}
```